# R: function to calculate power of one-sample binomial test

Tags: r

I've used the `bpower` function in `Hmisc` to calculate the power of a two-sample binomial test. But how can I calculate the power of a one-sample binomial test?

Comment: Have you looked at `?binom.test`

Comment: @SamThomas Hm, yes, but as far as I know the function doesn't tell me the power?

Comment: you could always figure it out yourself by simulation

Comment: @MichaelChirico Could you show me an example? Suppose my null hypothesis is p = 0.5 vs alternative hypothesis p > 0.5. My sample size is 1000. What's the power of the test at the 0.05 level?

Comment: You could always calculate it manually... I'm not aware of power functions in **R**, though to be fair I do power calcs **very** rarely. [GPower](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Science-CAD/G-Power.shtml) is a free program that will do it for you though

Comment: Check command "pwr.p.test" from pwr package.